# Authentication error: invalid signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

Copied and pasted from the docs, my code looks like this:

```
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
// API keys intentionally left blank
var client = new Client({
    'apiKey': '',
    'apiSecret': '',
    'version':'2018-06-04'
});

client.createAccount({'name': 'New Wallet'}, function(err, acct) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(acct.name + ': ' + acct.balance.amount + ' ' + acct.balance.currency);
});
```

However, `err` from the createAccount function is saying that I am getting an `Authentication error: invalid signature` error. Does anyone know why?

Solved: https://davidwalsh.name/coinbase

Coinbase's docs are terrible and out of date.

Comment: Did you check `err` to find out what what's wrong? That's why it's there....

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `err` is?

Comment: when I try to console.log(err), I get: AuthenticationError: invalid signature

Comment: Well…that's the answer to why `acct` is null, right?

Comment: Sorry - updated question